# algebraic expression - square root issue

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Assuming $x\ge1$. How to go from
$$
\frac{\sqrt {x-1}+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt {x-1}-\sqrt{x+1}}
$$
to
$$
-\sqrt{x^2-1}-x
$$
?

Comment: multiply top & bottom by $\sqrt {x-1}+\sqrt{x+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

divide and multiply by $(\sqrt{x-1}+ \sqrt{x+1})$
to get the answer

Comment: I'd suggest you learn and use mathjax.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks, i really needed it